# Filtering null object keys with flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have an object that has some null keys, e.g.:

```
type obj = Array<{key: ?number}>;
```

and I want to refine that by filtering out the null values to:

```
Array<{key: number}>
```

But I can't figure out how to make flow happy.  Simple repro ([try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAtiAq5oF4oG8BQUoGsIgC4oA7AVxgCMIAnAGgwF8MMBjAe2IGdgo2KArTlFQBtNHkIlSAG2kNa6CUQAsAJgYBdANzN2XHgDMAltOA0IAEyIBBatQCGIADxxEkAHzDeAzgDpjpjQAFHz8wp6hvhJQAISoZLIAlFpAA)):

```
type myType = {
  key: number,
}

const objs = [{key: null}, {key: 42}];

const filtered: Array<myType> = objs.filter(obj => obj.key != null);
```

Comment: Typecasting? ...

Comment: @JonasW. -- As a fallback, of course, I'd just prefer a solution that flow is happy with as casting through `any` is an ugly hack

Comment: I don't think that flow is able to infer the correct type here. And you could just cast it to `Array<myType>`

Comment: @JonasW. -- I don't see a way to cast straight to `Array<myType>` as flow can't cast `?type -> type`.  AFAIK you have to do `?type -> any -> type`

Answer (score 0):

Flow doesn't (currently) account for the fact that you can filter by type with `Array.prototype.filter`, so it just assumes the type doesn't change. If you *really* want to get Flow to understand what's going on here, you can always use a reduction:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAtiAq5oF4oG8BQUoGsIgC4oA7AVxgCMIAnAGgwF8MMBjAe2IGdgo2KArTlFQBtNHkIlSAG2kNa6CUQAsAJgYBdZuy48AZgEtpwGhAAmRAILVqAQxAAeOIkgA+YbwGcAdNXOkWCAAKLCgg2xYWBXF8BgBKYXcJKABCVDJZKAB+KBFvfIioxViNKCJC+mwRDTigA))

```
type myType = {
  key: number,
}

const objs = [{key: null}, {key: 42}]

// no error
const filtered: Array<myType> = objs.reduce(
  (acc, {key}) => key != null ? [...acc, {key}] : acc,
  [])
```

Flow can understand that `key` must not be null in this case. If you have other properties of `myType` you want to carry over, you can use this reducer to carry them over: `(acc, {key, ...rest}) => key != null ? [..acc, {...rest, key}] : acc`.

Alternatively, if you're sure what you're doing (and you have a unit test or something in place), you probably want to typecast through `any` to get the same effect:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAtiAq5oF4oG8BQUoGsIgC4oA7AVxgCMIAnAGgwF8MMBjAe2IGdgo2KArTlFQBtNHkIlSAG2kNa6CUQAsAJgYBdANzN2XHgDMAltOA0IAEyIBBatQCGIADxxEkAHzCoACj6CAdMamNL4Cwp5+-hJQAISoZLIAlET2xCCJQA))

```
type myType = {
  key: number,
}

const objs = [{key: null}, {key: 42}];

// no error
const filtered: Array<myType> = (objs.filter(obj => obj.key != null): any)
```

Personally, I find the typecast to be a lot more readable and it's easy to assert this logic is correct with a unit test or two.